# How to addClass() to list item based on current URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, addclass

My website currently has a pretty cool navigation bar, but I am looking to make it even better. Here is my question:

Can someone help me fix my JS Script so that depending on the current url, that list item in my menu will have the class "active", and all other list items with different URLs will remain their default, non-active classes?

I will provide my code so far.

HTML

```
      <li class="nav-home"><a href="index.php">home</a></li>

      <li class="dropdown nav-portfolio"><a href="portfolio.php">portfolio</a>

<ul>

          <li><a href="#">Photography</a></li>

          <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>

        </ul>

      </li>

      <li class="nav-aboutme"><a href="about-me.php">about me</a></li>

      <li class="dropdown nav-socialmedia"><a href="social-media.php">social media</a>

<ul>

          <li><a href="#">facebook</a></li>

          <li><a href="#">twitter</a></li>

          <li><a href="#">instagram</a></li>

          <li><a href="#">youtube</a></li>

          <li><a href="#">vine</a></li>

          <li><a href="#">snapchat</a></li>

          <li><a href="#">shots</a></li>

          <li><a href="#">google+</a></li>

        </ul>

      </li>

      <li class="nav-contact"><a href="contact.php">contact</a></li>

      <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">more</a>

        <ul>

          <li><a href="#">blog</a></li>

          <li><a href="#">faq</a></li>

          <li><a href="#">equipment</a></li>

        </ul>

      </li>

    </ul>
```

JS

```
if(window.location.href == "http://www.example.com/index.php"){
    $('.nav-home').addClass('active');
} else if(window.location.href == "http://www.example.com/portfolio.php"){
    $('.nav-portfolio').addClass('active');
} else if(window.location.href == "http://www.example.com/about-me.php"){
    $('.nav-aboutme').addClass('active');
} else if(window.location.href == "http://www.example.com/social-media.php"){
    $('.nav-socialmedia').addClass('active');
} else if(window.location.href == "http://www.example.com/contact.php"){
    $('.nav-contact').addClass('active');
} else {
    exit();
}
```

I have run my JS through a syntax checker, and it said it was all correct, however this code does not add the class to any of the list items. So just to summarize, if someone could help me fix my code that the class "active" is added to the list item that corresponds with the current url. (See JS for list items's and URL's) Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: So what is happening?

Comment: *however this code does not do what I want it to.* what does this mean? The classes are not being added at all or it gets added for all theurls?

Comment: My apologies, this code doesn't add the class to ANY of the list items @SudhansuChoudhary

Comment: Where have you placed your script?

Comment: is the whole code bound in `$(document).ready()`?? I mean the jQuery stuff?

Comment: it is place in the header @nikhil

Comment: yes @SudhansuChoudhary

Comment: If you have enclosed your code in document ready then the code should work. Can you add the exact html?

Comment: I think it's not safe to depend on exact URLs for those type of state updates. If you change your application URL for some reason in future this will break. Like others already suggested, it's better to use `switch` instead of all those if conditions, use exact matcher `===` . So do you see any errors in developers console (F12 -> Console) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this situation you should use switch

```
switch(expression) {
case n:
    code block
    break;
case n:
    code block
    break;
default:
    default code block
```

}

more information : http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

Comment: I will accept this answer because after reading about Switch case, it makes a lot more sense for what I am doing

Answer (score 0):

Is the code doing anything? You said it's not doing what you want it to do? What is it doing? Nothing? Try doing

```
alert(window.location.href)
```

and see what values you're actually getting. You could try doing

```
if(window.location.href === "http://www.example.com/index.php")
```

Comment: It's doing absolutely nothing (I updated my question, sorry for bad wording)

Comment: When I'm doing javascript coding I use alert('make my browser tell me something') all the time. If you don't get an alert you know your script isn't even loading correctly and at that point you could check the placement of the script.

Comment: Okay I'll try that and see if it's executing